# Regex to capture a group of delimited words that must end with a specific word

Tags: regex

I'm normalizing a bunch of Ansible group names, which have to change to use underscores instead of hyphens (thanks, Ansible). However, there's tons of other stuff in the file that is hyphenated, so I want to leave those lines alone. The ones I want to change always end with `-servers`. So, with a small sample, we might have:

```
foo-bar
foo-bar-servers
foo-bar-baz-servers
```

`(\w)-(\w?)?` very nicely captures things so I can just sub to `$1_$2` to change the hyphens to underscores. However, as soon as I add `-servers` or `ervers` on the end, it grabs only the very last pair around the hyphen. I have tried many variations, read up a little on lookaheads, and I am thoroughly stumped. It seems like it ought to be simple. What is the magic incantation to match *all* the groups around the hyphens, for lines ending in `-servers`? Many thanks in advance.

Edit: desired results, with apologies:

```
foo-bar
foo_bar_servers
foo_bar_baz_servers
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you would show the desired results for your three examples. Would they be `foo-bar` (no change), `foo_bar_servers` and `foo_bar_baz_servers`? Also please indicate what may precede the first letter of the string ending with "servers". Perhaps a space, a non-word character or the beginning of the string?

Answer (score 2):

As long as your regex engine supports positive lookaheads and (fixed-length) positive lookbehinds (as do most engines, including PCRE (PHP) and Python, for example), you may use the following regular expression to match the desired hyphens, which may then be replaced with underscores.

```
(?<=\w)-(?=(?:\w+-)*servers$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/R4wz8O/2/)

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?<=\w)       match a word char in a positive lookbehind
-             match a hypen
(?=           begin a positive lookahead
  (?:\w+-)    match 1+ word chars then '-', in a non-capture group
  *           execute non-capture group 0+ times
  servers     match string
  $           match end of line
)             end positive lookahead
```

Comment: Incredible! I figured look-behind had to be part of it, but the use of non-matching so all that's needed is `_` for the substitution is poetry. Thanks!